# hexadecimal NULL inside the string

Tags: c++

```
const char* sendbuf = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84";
```

But the result is ABCDX4
X == \x58 ,   4 == \x34

So my string got cut off in the middle. I understand it is because of **\x00**.

So how to have hexadecimal null \x00 in the middle of string ?

I am trying to send UDP packets.

Comment: What do you expect a null character to print out?  If you want to see "x00" then take the slash out from in front of it and print that string.  If you really want to print an actual null character then don't expect to see anything.

Comment: Your UDP send function will not be terminated by a NULL so this is just an artefact of printing this as a string. Write a print function of your own that takes a size and prints out each byte to confirm things are as you expect.

Comment: The terminating 0 is usual in C strings but nevertheless the language doesn't prevent you to have an array of `char`s with any values in (0 included). E.g. `std::string` handles the size separately which makes it more flexible although a terminating 0 is supported as well (for compatibility to C strings). Btw. I wouldn't wonder if the compiler adds another terminating 0 for `"ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84\x00"` because it does always for string literals. Not that issue but if you want prevent this you had to use `{ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', '4', '\0', '\x84', '\0' }` instead.

Comment: sorry the last \x00 was inserted by me for testing. I have scapy sniffing on the other side to see what data was actually send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with:

`const char* sendbuf = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84";`

is that you lose size information.

You would keep that information, if you use C-array

`const char sendbuf[/*8+1*/] = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84";`

or `std::string` literals:

```
using namespace std::literals;
const auto sendbuf = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84"s; // std::string with size 8
```

Then you can display/send your buffer:

```
auto s = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84"s;
std::cout << s;
sendUPD(/*..*/, s.c_str(), s.size());

char cs[] = "ABCD\x58\x34\x00\x84"s;
for (auto c : cs) { std::cout << c; } // "print" middle \0 and final one 
sendUPD(/*..*/, cs, sizeof(cs) - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

the problems was not with the const char * sendbuf

It was with another function which

```
send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, sizeof(sendbuf), 0);
```

Also i replaced const char sendbuf [];